# Open a Excel file and Activate sheet 1 to run macros

Tags: vba, excel

I need to write a VBA code that allows the user to browse and select an Excel file of his choice from a directory and then activate Sheet1 in that Excel file. After that I want macros to run on the activated sheet.

please help from below forward:

```
Sub GetFile()
Dim fNameAndPath As Variant, wb As Workbook
Dim sht As Worksheet

fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.XLSX), *.XLSX", Title:="Select File To Be Opened")
If fNameAndPath = False Then Exit Sub
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fNameAndPath)
```

From here how to activate the open file, and how to activate Sheet 1 of the open file to run macros?

Comment: You need a randomly chosen file?? Um, why?

Comment: what do you mean by sheet1? Is sheet1 the name of the tab, or you mean the 1st tab among all the tabs in the Excel file?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to `Activate` "Sheet1" in order to run Macros on it.

If you must `Activate` it, use :

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fNameAndPath)

' Option 1: set the first sheet (index)
Set Sht = wb.Worksheets(1) 
' Option 2: set the sheet named "Sheet1"
Set Sht = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")    

Sht.Activate ' <-- Not sure why you would need to Activate it ?
```

Comment: `Set Sht = wb.Worksheets(1)` can result in a wrong assignment if the name of the sheets is not as default names assigned by Excel itself.

Comment: @Ibo did you read the comments inside my code ? I gave him 2 options, as I am not sure if the PO meant "Sheet1", or the first Sheet (index wize)

Comment: Both of us can see his level from what he is asking and how he describes his need, so it is better to keep it simple for him until he learns about the index and the code name of sheet etc, however, I am not saying your answer is wrong, it can just be confusing for him

Answer (score 0):

The code will open the workbook and will assign the opened workbook to wb object. Automatically wb will be the active one, so there is no need to write a code for that. Just to make sure Sheet1 will be activated, you should add:

```
wb.sheets("Sheet1").activate
```

I did not quite get what you meant by "I want macros to run on the activated sheet." because it depends on the macro that is run. To make sure that the macro will use the active sheet to make changes etc you should use the object `activesheet` for example you can do this:

```
Dim ws as worksheet
set ws=activesheet
' ...
' do whatever you want on ws in here
' ...
```

Comment: If this is going to work on a "random" (i.e. user-selected) file, there is a very high probability that there won't be a sheet called "Sheet1".  It therefore seems like the OP is wanting to access the first sheet in the file, so it would probably be best to show how to access `Worksheets(1)` rather than `Worksheets("Sheet1")`.  (Or show them how to access both ways, so that they can use whichever method is appropriate.)

Comment: He says sheet1 and not the first sheet in the OP. The contrary is if he really wants Sheet1 (name of the sheet) and the code chooses the first index then  it can be a problem

Comment: The question refers to `Sheet1` (which would be a `CodeName`) and also (twice) to Sheet `1` (which would be an index into the `Sheets` collection), but doesn't mention `"Sheet1"` (which would be a `Name`), so perhaps giving all three methods and explaining what they do would be the best solution.  (Or perhaps wait until the questioner clarifies which they mean?)